# js two objects in one

Tags: javascript, json

I'm sorry I didn't express myself correctly

I have 3 sets. (BUT it can be more)

so.

I add maybe 3 Names.

```
const set = new Set();

set.add('Peter');
set.add('Jonas');
set.add('Joe');
...
but maybe more
```

Now I want to store all datas in one JSON object

Comment: Please update the question with the JSON you get, and the JSON you *want* to get instead. (Also: Are you **sure** you want JSON? E.g., a string? You might if you're sending it to a server or something...)

Comment: It's not clear to me what the HTML in the question has to do with the rest of the question. Your code just stores `{data: 1}` and `{data: 2}` in a set.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to send all datas to the backend server in json format, but I have 2 json objects. I editet my post with more code. I tried object.assign but its not working. It shows me for every letter a json object xd

Comment: Again, please show us the JSON you get, and the JSON you want. (For what it's worth: I suspect the `Set` is not what you want...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okey I editet my post^^

Comment: *"now I want that all datas in one json like"* You can't have repeated property keys like that. There can be only **one** `role` property, not two. Maybe you want an array? I'm afraid it's really hard to figure out what your end goal is. (I'm afraid I'm disappearing for the day. Good luck, I hope you figure it out!)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you can merge the two JavaScript objects using the [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```js
const a = {data: 2};
const b = {"firma":"asdasd","name":"sdaasd","email":"sdaasd","telefon":"sdasda"}
const sum = { 
  ...a,
  ...b
}
console.log(sum)
```